# Confused with the Output of the query

Tags: mysql, performance, oracle

i have to query emp_id from empmtg table on emp_mtg='141'along with name in the user table which i need to get in the same query.

```
SELECT emp.emp_id,mast.name
FROM empmtg emp,users mast
WHERE emp.emp_mtg='141';
```

This needs to select empid from empmtg table and name from users table on the condition that mtg id in the empmtg table should be 141. there are only 5 records in that table with mtg id as 141. but i am getting around 1000s of data.

also i tried this, but it is producing only 3 records output

```
SELECT emp.emp_id,mast.name
FROM empmtg emp,users mast
WHERE emp.emp_mtg='141' and emp.emp_id=mast.id
```

then i went for joins

```
SELECT emp.emp_id,mast.name
FROM empmtg emp
LEFT JOIN users mast
ON emp.emp_id=mast.id
WHERE emp.emp_mtg='141';
```

this is producing output of 5 records but the names are all null. i checked in the user table that the names are **not null**

i have one answer  **select inside select** which i think is not the correct way of doing. but i dont like to query in that way. but that produced result as expected.

Can anyone help me out for a better solution.

Comment: have you tried with INNER JOIN ?

Comment: yes. it is not even returning a single row

Comment: can you show this working query with subquery ?

Comment: select emp_id , (select name from users where id=emp_id)
from empmtg 
where emp_mtg='141'

Comment: some sample data if you want or fiddle ?

Comment: sorry. i could not do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35690/discussion-between-kalai-and-echo-me)

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT emp.emp_id,mast.name
 FROM  empmtg emp
 left JOIN  users mast
 ON emp.emp_id=mast.id
 WHERE emp.emp_mtg = 141;
```

here a [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afd433/5)

Comment: while copy paste i did some small mistake. but it is correct query only. dont check fr spell mistake and all. everything is correct. help in logic